# What does the input pattern value below mean?

Tags: html, forms, input

I've found this input pattern value from [this website](https://html5-tutorial.net/form-validation/validating-email/#:%7E:text=Try%20this%20example!-,/%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9.!%23%24%25%26%27*%2B/%3D%3F%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%7E-%5D%2B%40%5Ba-zA-Z0-9-%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z0-9-%5D%2B)*%24,-/).

`` ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$ ``

But, I don't know what this means as I don't really understand this input pattern stuff. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It is a **Regular Expression** used for validating an email address. the `pattern` attribute is used to accept only the inputs that follow the mentioned pattern.

Simply, to understand, the above Regular Expression accepts inputs of the form **xxx@yyy.yyy**
Here,
xxx should be anything between a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or the mentioned symbols. You can repeat the xxx any no. of times, like aabzz##.

after this, an @ symbol **must** be included.

Later, yyy could be anything, 1 or more times, among a-z or A-Z or 0-9, followed by a dot (.). After this dot, you should have atleast 1 character between a-z or A-Z or 0-9

Note: in yyy Symbols are not allowed according to the regular expression.

If all these requirements meet, then your input is valid, otherwise, it is invalid.